# Golang Mac OSX build for Docker machine

Tags: linux, macos, go, build, docker

I need to run Golang application on Docker machine.

I'm working on Mac OSX and Docker is working on top of Linux virtual machine, so binaries builded on Mac are not runnable on Docker.

I see two ways here:

1. cross-compile binaries on Mac for linux OS
2. copy project sources to docker, run 'go get' and 'go build' on it

First one is hard because of CGO (it is used in some imported libraries).

Second is very slow because of 'go get' operation.

Can you please tell me, which way is the most common in that situation? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Docker caches image layers, and allows you to start from a specific image. Break up the commands in the Dockerfile so that you can reuse as many layers as possible, and changes in your source only require building your own package.

Comment: JimB, but how can I break up 'go get' command? RUN go get package1 /n RUN go get package2... etc and they will be cached?

Comment: Don' use `go get`, or at least create an base image with it and start from there (`go get` shouldn't be used in production, so most people have some other method for managing dependencies). A basic solution in a single Dockerfile is to create a Makefile or script to install all deps as required, which can be put in a single RUN statement.

Comment: I've understood, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution to make cross-compile super easy even with CGO.

I stumbled upon it recently after wasting a lot of time getting a new windows build server to build my Go app.
Now I just compile it on my Mac and will create a Linux build server with it:

https://github.com/karalabe/xgo

Many thanks to Péter Szilágyi alias karalabe for this really great package!

How to use:

- have Docker running
- go get github.com/karalabe/xgo
- xgo --targets=windows/amd64 ./

There are lots more options!

-- edit --

Almost 3 Years later I'm not using this any more, but my docker image to build my application in a linux based CD pipeline is still based on the docker images used in `xgo`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the first approach. Here its a gulp task the build go code. If the production flag is set, it runs `GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build` instead  `go build`. So the binary will work inside a docker container

```
gulp.task('server:build', function () {
    var build;

    let options = {
        env: {
            'PATH': process.env.PATH,
            'GOPATH': process.env.GOPATH
        }
    }

    if (argv.prod) {
        options.env['GOOS'] = 'linux'
        options.env['CGO_ENABLED'] = '0'
        console.log("Compiling go binarie to run inside Docker container")
    }

    var output = argv.prod ? conf.paths.build + '/prod/bin' : conf.paths.build + '/dev/bin';
    build = child.spawnSync('go', ['build', '-o', output, "src/backend/main.go"], options);
    if (build.stderr.length) {
        var lines = build.stderr.toString()
            .split('\n').filter(function(line) {
                return line.length
            });
        for (var l in lines)
            util.log(util.colors.red(
                'Error (go install): ' + lines[l]
            ));
        notifier.notify({
            title: 'Error (go install)',
            message: lines
        });
    }
    return build;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Docker container from the distinct OS you need for your executable, and map a volume to your src directory. Run the container and make the executable from within the container.  You end up with a binary that you can run on the distinct OS.